# Convert iPhone GPS to address

Tags: iphone

I have been researching a few different apps lately for my company which are all able to convert your current GPS location to an address. I have been googling and searching through the stack but I can't seem to find any helpful information on the net to tell me how to achieve this. So my question is this; how do you:

a) get your current GPS coordinates and then
 b) transform them into a real address i.e. street number/name, city, country

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a) get your current GPS coordinates

You need to use CLLocationManager for that (you may need to store manager to release it when it no longer will be needed) -

```
CLLocationManager* manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
manager.delegate = self;
//Set location manager's properties if needed
[manager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Then your delegate object will be able to receive messages when GPS location updates (or fails to do that):

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

> b) transform them into a real address

After you have gps coordinate of tour location you can create `MKReverseGeocoder` object to query google reverse geocoding service. If request succeeds geocoder's delegate will receive `MKPlacemark` object with address info.

Answer (score 1):

Use `MKReverseGeocoder`

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

MKReverseGeocoder is deprecated in iOS 5.0. Use the **CLGeocoder** class instead.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/clgeocoder