# How to find address using latitude and longitude

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert iPhone GPS to address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690312/convert-iphone-gps-to-address)

hi,how to find address using latitude and longitude in iphonei

Comment: Please clarify. What did you tried? Do you need a service name that let you do that? Web-based solution, local solution??

Answer (score 3):

This is called "reverse geocoding".  Here is a sample:

http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/12/22/introduction-to-mapkit-in-iphone-os-3-0-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in 2 ways

1)  [CellIdentifier](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CurrentAddress/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009469-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) iphone example, its easy.

2) use a google map service from iphone, which can convert your address to Longitude and latitude here is the link

http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=###ADDRESS###&;output=###OUTPUT###&;key=###KEY###

Regards
Shahid

Answer (score 0):

import

```
#import "JSON.h"
```

I'm using json framework from
http://code.google.com/p/json-framework download that.

```
+(NSString *) getLocation:(double) lattitude logitude:(double) longitude
{
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%f,%f&sensor=false",lattitude,longitude];


    NSURL *urlFromString = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSStringEncoding encodingType = NSUTF8StringEncoding;
    NSString *reverseGeoString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:urlFromString encoding:encodingType error:nil];

    NSDictionary *locationResult = [reverseGeoString JSONValue];
    NSString *status = (NSString *)[locationResult objectForKey:@"status"];
    NSString *retVal = nil;
    if([status isEqualToString:@"OK"])
    {
        NSArray *results = [locationResult objectForKey:@"results"];
        if([results count] > 0)
        {
            NSDictionary *address=[results objectAtIndex:0];
            retVal = [address objectForKey:@"formatted_address"];
        }


    }   
    return retVal;
}
```