# How to find address in iPhone using latitude and longitude?

Tags: iphone

How to find address in iPhone using latitude and longitude?

Comment: What programming language are you using? What application are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert iPhone GPS to address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690312/convert-iphone-gps-to-address)

Answer (score 4):

This is called 'reverse geocoding', see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html